# Best operating system to install Kurento Media Server?

Tags: node.js

i hope to make a video conferencing application using kurento media server.
what is the best operating system to work with kurento media server? can we work with windows 10, without any doubts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend Linux (Example : Ubuntu, Linux Mint), Because Linux have most stable to install and coding Kurento Media Server.

Answer (score 2):

As stated on kurento documentation page http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide.html:

> Kurento Media Server (KMS) has explicit support for two Long-Term
>   Support (LTS) distributions of Ubuntu: Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) and
>   Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial). Only the 64-bits editions are supported.
>
> Currently, the main development environment for KMS is Ubuntu 16.04
>   (Xenial), so if you are in doubt, this is the preferred Ubuntu
>   distribution to choose.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and haven't had any problems so far. Also it is possible to set it up on Windows (https://github.com/kirushyk/kms-windows).

Comment: is it dualboot or virtual machine?

Comment: it is virtual machine in cloud